# Which indexes are used on CD?

Tags: indexing

Please can somebody tell me that what all indexes are being used from the content delivery server in Sitecore?

In Sitecore 9.1 below are the index available:

- sitecore_core_index
- sitecore_master_index
- sitecore_web_index
- sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master
- sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web
- sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master
- sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web
- sitecore_testing_index
- sitecore_suggested_test_index
- sitecore_fxm_master_index
- sitecore_fxm_web_index

As per my understanding, it seems that following are being used by Content Delivery servers:

- sitecore_core_index
- sitecore_web_index
- sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web
- sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web
- sitecore_fxm_web_index

Kindly correct me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**sitecore_core_index** is not used for CD server. The rest is correct.

You can check search indexes requirements in a scalable environment here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-search-indexes-required-in-a-scalable-environment.html